# VS 2012 - Solution Explorer show (slow)

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

I'm working on a web site (not web aplication project) and I have problems with IDE performance. For example when I add a new class to the project or I'm working on an existing one and click the Solution Explorer, before the window shows there it takes a lot of time and freezes VS.
I'm looking for which options to disable in VS, because it's really annoying.
For now I unchecked the Track Active Items in Solution Explorer in Options/Projects and Solutions/General, but there must be something else.
I have VS 2012 Premium.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows SysInternals website has a tool called Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb842062) that can sniff registry and file accesses by any running program. You can try to find what takes so long by using this tool.

Take a look at this article as well: http://blog.geocortex.com/2007/12/07/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/ - in that case the reason was a folder C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, duDE!

My VS Solution Explorer (VS 2013 Community) was being super-slow. 

The problem turned out to be my Perforce P4VS plugin had the "Automatically update files status when selection changes" box checked, which was causing the Solution Explorer to be super-sluggish.

SysInternals Process Monitor helped me track that down quite quickly.